# Send click from Stateless Parent Component To Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic button in a stateless component and want to send a click to the child PureComponent.
If the parent component had state it would be sent via a method that changed the state and pass that state in a prop to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send a function as a prop to the child component.
Like:

```
handleClick=()=>{
  //your code
 }
  <childComponent clickFunction={this.handleClick}></childComponent>
```

And use the function in the child component in the following way:

```
this.props.clickFunction()
```